# Firebase rule permission denied when deleting

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am trying to learn using Firebase rules, but having some trouble. I have two nodes in my database a `meetups` and `comments`. Both have a `meetupID` property. I am trying to write a rule so that any writes to the `comments` node only happen if a child under `meetups` exists matching the `meetupID`of a comment. Saving a new value to `comments` works fine, but deleting gives me a permission denied. Here is what I have:

```
"comments": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
      "$meetupID": {
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('meetups').hasChild($meetupID)"
    },
```

I suspect this is because when I delete a meetup from the app I also delete the comments for that meetup at the same time which causes this rule to deny permission. Is there some way I can re-write this rule to make it work successfully for both saving and deleting values?

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: Option 1: Make sure you delete the comments before the meetup. Option 2: Take a look at [newData](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#newdata) to check if it's null or something like that.

Comment: Hey @AndréKool thanks for the reply! I will give deleting the comments before the meetup a shot. For now i was able to get it working by doing a query in-app on meetups to see if it exists before writing any comment. Seems to be working properly, but going to give your suggestions a shot. Thanks again!